# How to keep '.00'

Tags: javascript

How to keep '.00' in Javascript? I currently have the string `"123456789012.00"`;
I want to get the double `123456789012.00` to keep `.00`

- `toFixed(2)` will return a string
- `parseFloat()` will cast the `.00`

How can I do this?

Comment: The `.00` is implicitly being kept.

Comment: What is the context, why do you want to do that?

Comment: I can't think of any time you could tell if there was a `.00` there or not without it being converted to a string for rendering … so I don't see that the problem with `toFixed` is.

Comment: assuming that you have a string.."123456789012.00".substr(13,2)

Comment: I am not sure but this might be what could be possible var number = Number(string);

Comment: numerically 123456789012.00 is equal to 123456789012. Why do you need to keep the `.00`

Comment: actually, I want to post a request through get/post, the data organized in json format, so they want to a double value, but my value is, ex, 12, I should give the the value in `12.00` in representation. so this is the requirement.

Comment: Take care of the representation when you display the JSON in your application.

Answer (score 8):

A float uses the precision it needs (that's why it's called a "float" -- as in "floating point", the point has no fixed position).

If you want to *display* a float with the 2 significant digits (i.e. 2 digits after the point), you can use `toFixed(2)`. That will not change the number, but will store it in a string with the number of digits you want to show.

Comment: Yes, I think so, my questions is so stupid! but I have no way to make them change the requirement.

Comment: What exactly is that requirement?? Is it that you must maintain a numeric precision of 2 digits? Because that is something you can do by `myVariable = parseFloat(myVariable.toFixed(2));`

Comment: but if the two digit are `.00`, it still be removed

Comment: thanks for your reply, but this method will return a string, I am still want to a double value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) method to do this. The code below will log the result you want in the console of your browser.

```
var num = "123456789012.00";
console.log(parseFloat(num).toFixed(2));
```

Comment: how can I get the return value of `console.log(parseFloat(num).toFixed(2));`? so there is no way, actually I think my question is so stupid, but I can't change the requirement.

Comment: where do you want to use this value?

Comment: It shouldn't matter in your JSON-file, `123456789012.00` is the same as `123456789012`. Take care of the representation when you display the JSON in your application.